# Android app installed but won't run

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

I started a new application and after settling my issues I started to make it. In the process I made a simple splash screen, but when I start the emulator it installs and won't run.

XML manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pathfinderapprentice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.pathfinderapprentice.SPALSH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pathfinderapprentice.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.pathfinderapprentice.MAIN_ACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the java class

```
package com.example.pathfinderapprentice;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
                            "com.example.pathfinderapprentice.MAIN_ACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you better add error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined an Activity called

```
com.example.pathfinderapprentice.Splash
```

in your Manifest. Just correct this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.pathfinderapprentice.SPALSH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

to

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pathfinderapprentice.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your Manifest file.THis error happens when you have declared same activity twice in manifest or you have define two activities as main activity.

in activity tag you have define name as
    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"

you have to define name here like this

```
android:name="com.example.pathfinderapprentice.MainActivity"
```

and dont modify whats inside intent.

your activity tag should look like this

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Convert"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your manifest is wrong:

```
    <activity
        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.pathfinderapprentice.SPALSH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Should be

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

On top of that, you shouldn't use a thread for this kind of timer, just use a `Handler` and then use either `postDelayed()` or `postAtTime()`.